# Javascript google maps API directions result, location object not returning lat or lng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

A bit of an obscure title I know, my issue is with trying to pull out the lat and lng info from the start and end locations of the steps within a direction service return object.

sample code, the callback from a directions request as such:

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    for (var routeItr = 0; routeItr < response.routes.length; routeItr++) {    // each route in the response
        for (var legItr = 0; legItr < response.routes[routeItr].legs.length; legItr++) {   // each leg in the route
            for (var stepItr = 0; stepItr < response.routes[routeItr].legs[legItr].steps.length; stepItr++) {      // each step in the leg
                alert(response.routes[routeItr].legs[legItr].steps[stepItr].start_location.lat);
            }
        }
    }
  }
})
```

you would assume that the alert there would return the lat number, instead it shows this:

[image]

Is this an issue my end? am I not understanding how this direction response object works? or an issue with my browser? or a bug in google's code?

Comment: Are you not providing the directions service with a start and an end point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) does not have a .lat property.  It has a .lat() method that returns the latitude.

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    for (var routeItr = 0; routeItr < response.routes.length; routeItr++) {    // each route in the response
        for (var legItr = 0; legItr < response.routes[routeItr].legs.length; legItr++) {   // each leg in the route
            for (var stepItr = 0; stepItr < response.routes[routeItr].legs[legItr].steps.length; stepItr++) {      // each step in the leg
                alert(response.routes[routeItr].legs[legItr].steps[stepItr].start_location.lat());
            }
        }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! don't know why i missed that, ive been using google LatLng for a while now